# Get shipping address values instead of billing in osCommerce credit card module

Tags: php, oscommerce

How can I get the shipping address values (`$sendto`) in the cc.php (creditcard.php module)?

Right now the module populates the billing firstname and billing lastname variables with the following code:

```
'field' => tep_draw_input_field('cc_owner', $order->billing['firstname'] . 
  ' ' . $order->billing['lastname'])),
```

I would like the module to populate the field with the **Shipping Address firstname and Shipping address Lastname**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out the answer. Change the above code to

```
'field' => tep_draw_input_field('cc_owner', $order->delivery['firstname'] . ' ' . $order->delivery['lastname'])),
```